# Want to add multiple variables to myql AND function

Tags: mysql, sql, addition

A screenshot:
[image]

Hi i want to add another number to `functie.code =` So that i get the results of people with the functie.code = 3 4 and 5.

But how should i do this?

```
SELECT distinct voornaam,achternaam,provincie,functie.naam,max(provincie)
FROM medewerker,functie,persoon,adres
WHERE medewerker.Functie_Code = functie.Code
AND medewerker.Persoon_idPersoon = persoon.idPersoon
AND persoon.Adres_idAdres = adres.idAdres
AND functie.code IN ( 3, 4, 5)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want `where functie.code IN ( 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: hi @jarlh. If i do that i get an sql syntax error

Comment: In your specific case replace `functie.code = 3` with `functie.code IN ( 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: hi @jarlh thanks that helped

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: hi @TobySpeight Im having trouble inserting the code in the question. it says foramtting fault

Comment: You should be able to insert your code using your platform's usual select/paste mechanism, and then mark it as code with the `{}` button.  Perhaps [Markdown Help](/editing-help) might have something useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `max()` in the `select`.  That turns the query into an aggregation query without a `group by` -- which returns exactly one row.

In addition, you are using archaic join syntax.  Simple rule:  Don't use commas in the `from` clause.

A query like this presumably does what you want:

```
SELECT voornaam, achternaam, provincie, f.naam, provincie
FROM medewerker m JOIN
     functie f
     ON m.Functie_Code = f.Code JOIN
     persoon p
     ON m.Persoon_idPersoon = p.idPersoon JOIN
     adres a
     ON p.Adres_idAdres = a.idAdres
WHERE f.code IN ( 3, 4, 5);
```

It is unclear whether or not you need `SELECT DISTINCT`.  If you don't, then don't use it unnecessarily in a query.

Comment: Hey thanks this also works. I have another question how can i make the query in such way that it only displays the provincie which has the most medewerkers? That would help a ton